# How to delete using HQL?

Tags: hibernate, hql, hql-delete

I'm using this example:
http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-query-examples-hql/

And trying to delete this way:

```
String qhl = "delete from logs  where dateTtime >= current_date - interval '1 month'";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
return query.executeUpdate();
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: line 1:61: unexpected token: '1 month'
Mai 23, 2014 3:07:22 PM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter reportError
ERROR: line 1:61: unexpected token: '1 month'
line 1:61: unexpected token: '1 month'
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.identPrimary(HqlBaseParser.java:4016)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:859)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3390)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3168)
...
```

When trying this:

```
String qhl = "delete from logs where dateTtime >= ( select cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date) )";
```

The error is:

```
logs is not mapped [delete from logs where dateTtime >= ( select cast(date_trunc('month', current_date) as date) )]
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what is interval '1 month'? where did you get this from?

Comment: I think it's PSQL (PostgreSQL) specific. It returns the last month date starting today ( Now() - 30 days ).

Comment: it wont work then, you need to go through the HQL specification and generate a query that it supports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not valid hql, just use the [native query functionality](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html) of hibernate instead, for vendor specific database functions.